# Download a file from a server using QT5

Tags: qt, qnetworkaccessmanager, qurl

I am trying to access a file from a server but instead of getting the desired file I get index.php. If I use a URL like http://domain.com/file.mp3 works fine but I need to use a url like "http://domain.com/index.php?security=access_recording".

If I use "http://domain.com/index.php?security=access_recording" in browser I get the correct file.
Can anyone help me?

```
manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
        this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://domain.com/index.php?security=access_recording")));
```

Comment: So you are getting only html content back? Is there any error, etc? Please do share the actual output.

Comment: [Here](http://i.imgur.com/Go23ZBu.png) is the output when I use "http://domain.com/index.php?security=access_recording"

Comment: And [here](http://i.imgur.com/31nZiwD.png) for  http://domain.com/file.mp3      Many thanks!!

Comment: Remove domain cookies in browser and try to download file or try to set user agent

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help...